# Not able to get cookie value as Jmeter variable (HTTP cookie manager) which doens't have label

Tags: jmeter

Not able to get cookie value as Jmeter variable (HTTP cookie manager) which doens't have label.

In our .Net application, there are 3 cookie values in the request as given below:

Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=1axjnxqp; xx yy Pvt. Ltd.; compNameSelected=xx yy Pvt. Ltd.

if observed, the middle value doesn't have label (xx yy pvt. ltd). This value is not being captured as cookie in subsequent requests though added HTTP cookie manager, updated user.properties file with CookieManager.save.cookies=true.

Used Debug sampler, only two ASP.NET and comNameSelected are shown.

Please suggest and guide.

Comment: try setting jmeter.properties: `CookieManager.check.cookies=false`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i had added this also in my user properties file but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `cookies`
- Regular Expression: `Set-Cookie: (.*)`
- Template: `$1$`
- Match No: `-1` (just in case there will be > 1 "Set-Cookie" header)

[image: JMeter Extract Cookies]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks for guiding. Cookies are not in my request's response. These values are in request only.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Dmitri T answer with a small change to make it work:

In the Regular Expression Extractor, On Field to check choose Request Headers

It will get cookie value from request.